# Installation SASS fails on MacOS

Tags: node.js, macos, sass, rubygems, gulp-sass

After running the installation command on mac with ruby `2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859)[universal.x86_64-darwin17]`

I see the following error:

```
<"ERROR: While executing gem ... (URI::InvalidURIError) URI must be ascii only "?gems=\u{2013}">
```

Could you help me with that guys, please ??

Comment: Please format your question properly and give more context about what you were doing

Comment: Please add the command you are running.

Comment: i am using both of this commands: gem install sass and sudo gem install sass.

Comment: Ok, a quick Q/A. You want to use `gulp-sass` npm right? There is no need to install sass to use `gulp-sass` because it uses `node-sass` that is sass for nodejs. Right?

Comment: That's right Stamos !!so basically that two different types of sass yes? I'm super fresh with all of it, and I started to panic when I couldn't install it.

Comment: No there are no two different types of sass. Only one, "sass compiler", many implementations, wrappers around that.

Comment: Ok ,so now i was trying to install gulp and i have this type of wanings on my console : npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.11: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js